dynamically sized grid items in react-grid-layout
I'm working on a custom dashboard with widgets using React grid layout, and I want the height of the grid item to be dynamically sized depending on the height of the widget component inside it. For example, if I have a to-do list widget and is 20px high by default, the grid item will be 20px. and if I add a task to that list, the height of the widget will change and thusly the grid item height will change. Is there any built in way with RGL to accomplish this?
I've tried setting the height to 'fit-content', but RGL uses explicit height and width so that didn't seem to work.

did you try height: auto !important; or height: unset !important; ? That should reset the height
